In a Frequentist setting, how are we able to condition on the null hypothesis being True/False?
Paraphrasing Casella and Berger (2002): A hypothesis test is defined by a null hypothesis $H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0 $ and an alternative hypothesis $H_1: \theta \in \Theta_0^c = \bar{H_0}$, where $\Theta$ is a set of possible values of the population parameter $\theta$, and $\Theta_0^c = \Theta - \Theta_0 $.
In the Frequentist setting, $\theta$ is an unknown but fixed quantity (meaning, it is non-random). As a result, for a given set $\Theta_0$, the null hypothesis $H_0$ is strictly True or False (but we do not know which). The alternative hypothesis, being the negation, is correspondingly False or True.
Let our test statistic be $\hat{\theta} = f(X_1, ..., X_n)$. We define the rejection region $RR \subset Range(\hat{\theta})$ as the set of values of the test statistic $\hat{\theta}$ for which we choose to reject $H_0$. As our sample $X_1, ..., X_n$ is random, $\hat{\theta}$ is a random variable, and so the quantity $p(\hat{\theta} \in RR)$ is a valid probability, similar to simpler probabilities like $p(X \le 5)$
So far so good. However, my confusion begins when we start to define Type I errors. A Type I error is when we reject $H_0$ even though it is True. This is defined mathematically as:
$$
\alpha = p(\hat{\theta} \in RR | H_0 \text{ is True}) = p(\hat{\theta} \in RR | \theta \in \Theta_0)
$$
This probability makes no sense to me. $\theta$ is not a random variable, so $\theta \in \Theta_0$ is not a probabilistic event, it is a True-or-False value. The framework of probability (as far as I understand it) does not allow us to meaningfully condition on real values or booleans, only on events.
What is going on here? The only meaningful interpretation I can make is if $\theta$ is a random variable, which violates the core idea of Frequentist statistics.

I am not sure I understand your concern? When we use the notation $P(A|B)$ to express conditional probabilities, the condition B is never a random variable; by definition it is assumed to be true, to have occured, and hence its probability is always 1. So $P(\hat \theta \in RR|\theta = {\theta}_0)$ is perfectly valid. As an answer noted (+1), it is a bit more complex for composite nulls, but usually that gets back to the above case, because it is sufficient to compute this in the "worse case", which is a single $\theta_0$ value.

@jginestet That seems to be at odds with Bayes' theorem.

@Dave, "seem" being the proper term. Yes, if you apply Bayes' theorem to P(A|B), you end up with a $P(B)$ term; do you set it to 1? No. That term is a prior: prior probability of B being true. So what is the prior for $\theta=\theta_0$? See e.g. Colquhoun's paper (in Appendix A) https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.140216 where he uses Bayes' theorem for significance tests (whic is basically the context of the OP's question).

@jginestet In the Frequentist setting, $\theta$ is fixed but unknown, so we do not know whether “$\theta \in \Theta_0$” is True. This term is also not an event in the probabilistic sense. How, then, do we justify conditioning on it within the framework of conditional probability? That is the core of my question.

You're right that the notation of the form $P(X|H_0)$ is misleading if this is supposed to be a frequency distribution for $X$ under a particular model assumption. I have seen people who know what they're talking about use it as shorthand, but I've also seen people sleepwalk into using it without fully appreciating what's going on.
If we're being careful, we will use different notation. In grad school, I think we used the notation $P(X;H_0)$. This is not written as a conditional probability, and is not meant to be interpreted as one. Rather, it should be read as something like "the probability (density) of $X$ under the probability model parameterized according to $H_0$." You'll notice that Casella and Berger, who you cite, are also careful and use notation such as $P_{\theta_0}(X)$ (where $H_0$ is such that $\theta=\theta_0$; page 388).

Thanks @JohnMadden, this makes sense. Do you mind expanding your answer to flesh out the exact statistical model we assume in hypothesis testing? I have not found a text which mentions it in detail (I have been searching in Casella and Wackerly)

@AbhishekDivekar the model you assume depends on your problem and has nothing to do with the interpretation. $H_0$ can be anything, it's the current best model. In physics, it's for example derived from a fundamental law and a complicated model. In economics, this may be a linear function.

@Mayou36 I see the term “statistical model used in a hypothesis test” mentioned in a number of other answers but cannot find a formal definition of it. I feel like a definition of the statistical model in terms of general quantities like Θ, θ, RR, sample space, etc. would be a good addition to this answer.

@AbhishekDivekar a statistical model (for us) is nothing more than a specification of a distribution for observable quantities. So for example, "this coin is fair e.g. P(X=Heads)=$\theta$=0.5" is an example of a statistical model. The difference is that for the Frequentist, this is the entire model. Whereas for the Bayesian, the statistical model consists of (whether implicitly or explicitly) a joint distribution placed on $\theta,X$ together. Subsequently, the Bayesian achieves a conditional distribution on $X|\theta$. (In practice, this joint distribution is often specified implicitly by...

... way of first defining $P(X|\theta)$ and $P(\theta)$).

@Mayou36 "current best model" seems a bit off (like you are conflating inferential machinery and preferences for use), since hypotheses may be framed in different ways (e.g., two directions for one-sided tests over a (possibly infinite) range of possible cutoff values, the two-sided test, two one-sided tests for equivalence with a (possibly infinite) range of equivalence thresholds). So maybe "current chosen model"? Also: Jonh Madden +1

@Alexis "best" refers to $H_0$, in this sence the "best" knowledge, the current knowledge. But you're right, it can just be an approximation of anything, so yes, it's a chosen model

Isn't replacing $|$ with $;$ just a semantical issue with how people use notation? And is there a large difference between 'conditional probability' versus 'the probability (density) of X
under the probability model parameterized according to H0'? I can reformulate the latter as 'the probability (density) of X conditional on it being under the probability model parameterized according to H0' and it doesn't change it's meaning.

@SextusEmpiricus  It's true that mathematically, the object $P(X;\theta)$ for the frequentist corresponds to the same function from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ (say) as the object $P(X|\theta)$ does for the Bayesian. However, ontologically, the thing is that if $\theta$ is not a random variable, conditioning on it is a category error: for the frequentist there is then no such thing as the object $P(X|\theta)$, just as there is no such thing as the object $P(X|\textrm{Tomato Paste})$.

@JohnMadden while I don't believe that $\theta$ is necessarily not random, why would this be necessary on order to speak about 'conditioning' on it. When did the meaning 'conditioning on' start to have this requirement for $X$ and $\theta$ to be a joint probability distribution?

@SextusEmpiricus ah maybe it's best to start a chat, but of course elementary definitions of conditional distributions explicitly reference joint distributions, and if you have a separate, measure-theoretically sophisticated definition in mind instead we can discuss that too.

The conditional probability $P(X|\theta)$ might have some restricted meaning in certain definitions, like in measure theory, but does that have to be generally?

@SextusEmpiricus The elementary, general purpose definitions of conditional probability that I've come across, like those on Wiki's Conditional Probability distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution or Conditional Probability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability seem to explicitly reference joint distributions and/or the fact that the conditioned upon object is a random variable. Though there are many ways to skin a cat and if you can share a definition that doesn't I'd be super interested in it :)

The issue here seems to be more about simplified notation than a conceptual error. Let’s break it down in more detail:
You wrote:
$$  
P(\hat{\theta} \in RR \mid \theta \in \Theta_0) = \alpha  
$$
This expression doesn't make sense when $\Theta_0$ contains more than one element, i.e., when you have a composite null hypothesis. In this case, you are not specifying a single probability distribution, as $\theta$ can take multiple values within $\Theta_0$.
Case 1: Simple Null Hypothesis
When the null hypothesis $H_0$ is simple, for example, $\Theta_0 = \{\theta_0\}$, the computation of $\alpha$ is straightforward and can be expressed as:
$$  
P_{\theta_0}(\hat{\theta} \in RR) = \alpha,  
$$
Here, $\alpha$ represents the probability that the statistic $\hat{\theta}$ falls within the rejection region $RR$, given that the true value of $\theta$ is $\theta_0$. The subscript in $P_{\theta_0}$ indicates that the probability is calculated under the assumption that $\theta = \theta_0$, and the distribution is fully specified.
Case 2: Composite Null Hypothesis
When $\Theta_0$ contains multiple possible values, as in a composite null hypothesis, there isn’t a single $\theta$ value tied to $H_0$. This makes the interpretation of $\alpha$ more complex. In this case, the significance level is typically defined as the supremum of the rejection probability over all values of $\theta$ in $\Theta_0$:
$$  
\alpha = \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_{\theta}(\hat{\theta} \in RR).  
$$
This ensures that $\alpha$ represents the maximum Type I error rate, regardless of the specific value of $\theta$ within $\Theta_0$. In other words, this definition guarantees that the significance level does not exceed $\alpha$ for any parameter value allowed under the null hypothesis.

+1 as this answer corrects my definition of Type I error to be more precise. However it does not answer the core question, which is about the interpretation of the conditional term $\theta \in \Theta_0$.

(After reading more over the last month, I have decided to answer my own question. My answer will expand on John Madden's, adding more background exposition).

It's correct that $p(\hat{\theta} \in RR | \theta \in \Theta_0)$ is not a meaningful quantity in all cases. This is a (common) abuse of notation, which hides the complexity of what's going on.
In Frequentist Hypothesis testing, we actually deal with three binary quantities:

The nature of reality (i.e. is $H_0$ True or False).
Our initial assumption (which is always that $H_0$ is True i.e. we assume the null model).
Our test inference which is based on the gathered data (i.e. our realized sample).

When performing a hypothesis test:

We assume our data was generated either under the null or alternate model. These models are idealisations; neither will capture all details of the true data-generating distribution (except in very limited situations). However, in often these models are reasonable representations of reality, and allow us to gain useful insights.
We initially assume That $H_0$ is true, i.e. that our sample was generated under the null model. However, we do not claim this assumption is correct and that $H_0$ is true in reality.
Instead, we use the realized sample, which is our best representation of reality, to conduct a test and obtain the test inference. We shall denote the test inference by a statistic $\psi_0 = f(X_1, ..., X_n) \in \{0, 1\}$.
Note that $\psi_0$ is not the same as the test statistic $\hat{\theta}$. Instead, $\psi_0$ acts as an indicator for the decision we will make: if the realized sample gives us $\psi_0 = 1$, we decide to reject our assumption that $H_0$ is True, otherwise if we get $\psi_0 = 0$, we accept our assumption that $H_0$ is True. We use the subscript "0" in $\psi_0$ to denote that this statistic is computed under the null model.

There are multiple ways to define $\psi_0$: above we used a rejection region RR ($\psi_0 = \hat{\theta} \in RR$), but critical values, p-values, etc are also valid. The key point however, is that we never claim to know for certain the true nature of reality (i.e. whether $H_0$ is True or False). Our realized sample simply provides us with evidence based on which we make an inference: a decision to accept or reject $H_0$.
This leads to four cases:

If in reality $H_0$ is True, then the null model $(E, \{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}\}_{\theta \in \Theta_0}) $ is correct. Consequently, let the "true" parameter be some $\theta_0 \in \Theta_0$. Our sample is thus drawn from the distribution parameterized by $\theta_0$, i.e. $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \mathbb{P}_{\theta_0}$


Case (1a): if the realized sample causes $\psi_0 = 0$, then we will accept $H_0$ as compatible with out data. This is the correct decision (i.e. our inference is aligned with reality)
Case (1b): if the realized sample causes $\psi_0 = 1$, then we will then we will reject $H_0$ as incompatible with our data. This is an error, since in reality $H_0$ is True. We call this a Type-1 error.


If in reality $H_0$ is False, then the alternate model $(E, \{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}\}_{\theta \in \Theta_1}) $ is correct. Consequently, let the "true" parameter be some $\theta_1  \in \Theta_1$, s.t. $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \mathbb{P}_{\theta_1}$. Note: here, we will use $\psi_1$ as our indicator statistic (subscript "1" denotes it was computed under the alternate model).


Case (2a): if the realized sample causes $\psi_1 = 1$, then we will reject $H_0$ as incompatible with our data. This is the correct decision.
Case (2b): if $\psi_1 = 1$, we accept $H_0$ as compatible, even though it is False. This is called a Type-II error.

A Type-I error is only defined when $H_0$ is True in reality, and a Type-II error is only defined in the case when $H_0$ is False in reality. To actually calculate the probability of making these errors, we must know the true nature of reality. Our hypothesis test only gives us an inference, not the true nature of reality, so we will never know the probability of a Type-I and Type-II error.
However, it turns out we can actually limit the probability of Type-I and Type-II errors to be an arbitrarily small value. Concretely, we first define the worst-case probabilities of these errors as:

$\alpha$ = "significance level" = $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \left[ \mathbb{P}_{\theta} (\psi_0 = 1) \right]$
$\beta$ = 1 - "power" = $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_1} \left[ \mathbb{P}_{\theta} (\psi_1 = 0) \right]$

We call these "worst-case" because they are the maximum possible error-probability across any choice of $\theta$ in the respective statistical model.
Thus, the probability of making an error is upper-bounded to be $\alpha$ (if $H_0$ is True in reality) or $\beta$ (if $H_0$ is False in reality). We can adjust the criterion for rejection in our hypothesis testing procedure, to give as small an $\alpha$ or $\beta$ we desire. For example, if we reduce the size of the rejection region RR, we will reduce $\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is a guaranteed worst-case on the error, regardless of the sample we realize or the true nature of reality, we can guarantee that our inference $\psi_0$ has a low chance of being incorrect.
However, this guarantee comes with the tradeoff: reducing the size of RR decreases $\alpha$ but also increases $\beta$, and vice-verca. The only way to reduce both errors, is by increases the sample size "n" (i.e. obtaining more datapoints from the true distribution).

"It's correct that $p(\hat{\theta} \in RR | \theta \in \Theta_0)$ is not a meaningful quantity. This is a (common) abuse of notation," For a point hypothesis it is not really an abuse of notation and the quantity is meaningful. It is only for a composite hypothesis that the probability depends on an additional nuisance parameter, and this needs to be handled in some way (e.g. integrate it ocer some prior, or choose the worst case).

My comment on this answer is that the $H_0$ is a mathematical model and as such an idealisation. It won't be true in reality (and neither will be the alternative, as far as it's formalised). Saying that "we assume it is true" just  means that we base the probability computations for the test on it. We shouldn't really "believe it is true". Also, if we don't reject it, it means that it is compatible with the data given the specific test statistic. It isn't necessarily "plausible", it may well be implausible for other reasons.

@SextusEmpiricus > "The significance level  is not the same as a p-value": I do not see where in my answer this was said? I said that the decision to accept or reject $H_0$ is based on rejection regions, critical values, and p-values.

@ChristianHennig I will add these points, thanks.

@AbhishekDivekar you are right, I completely misread it.

@SextusEmpiricus could you explain why $p(. | \theta = \theta_0)$ is not an abuse but $p(. | \theta \in \Theta_0)$ is? I claim that both of these are abuses: if $\theta$ was a random variable, then both $\theta = \theta_0$ and $\theta \in \Theta_0$ would be events, and the conditional probabilities would be meaningful. But since $\theta$ is a fixed quantity, these two are predicates (i.e. they are either True or False). Conditioning on True/False is not well defined as far as I can tell.

[...] I don't really understand the argument "the first one means the same thing as $\mathbb{P}_{\theta_0}(.)$ so we should do it". I mean, sure, you can condition endlessly on as many True statements as you want, but it's (a) confusing (b) wrong in the general case of a composite hypothesis. I will, however, modify the answer to add this point in the first line.

@AbhishekDivekar "could you explain why..." for point hypotheses these expressions $P(X|\theta)$ can be interpreted as a likelihood function. For composite hypotheses a likelihood function does not exist.

Interestingly Wikipedia tells in the article about likelihoods „In the frequentist paradigm, the notation
f(x∣θ) is often avoided and instead f(x;θ) or f(x,θ) are used to indicate that
θ is regarded as a fixed unknown quantity rather than as a random variable being conditioned on.”. Then it is just a matter of style.

@ChristianHennig fixed, please take a look if this is what you intended.

"The nature of reality" is that no model is "true", so I wouldn't start by saying that $H_0$ is true or not. Furthermore, the wording "accept $H_0$" in case of non-rejection is misleading, though used widely. It's not the point of a test that we could "accept $H_0$ to be true" as in reality it isn't, and we should know this before running the test. At best it may be a reasonable model, but this cannot be decided by a test alone.

There can be three issues with the expression $P(X|H_0)$
TLDR

In a Frequentist setting, how are we able to condition on the null hypothesis being True/False?

In a frequentist setting you don't need to condition on the null hypothesis in the sense of a measure theoretical conditional distribution. But often the used likelihood coincides with a conditional distribution anyways and terms get used in a sloppy way.
1 Point hypothesis versus composite hypothesis

In a Frequentist setting, how are we able to condition on the null hypothesis being True/False?

For a point hypothesis the model is exactly determined and we can exactly compute a conditional probability using basic rules of probability.
There might be some trickery like the Borel Kolmogorov paradox. But typically the conditioning on the parameter is not done explicitly via the definition $P(X|\theta) = P(X,\theta)/P(\theta)$ or when it has zero measure like $P(\theta) =0$, with a limiting process. Instead it is computed indirectly as the likelihood function for a parametric distribution. I guess that practitioners of Bayesian statistics also often take this approach of defining the likelihood independent from $P(\theta)$ as often a decision is already made about a likelihood before there is a prior, and discussions and arguments about the right prior for a given likelihood are all around.
For a composite hypothesis the model is not exactly determined and there is an unknown nuisance parameter. We do not exactly condition solely on the null hypothesis, and some additional assumptions are made about that nuisance parameter. For example we condition on the observed values (like Fisher's exact test), use the worst case scenario (like Barnard's test or likelihood ratio test), or integrate over some prior.
2 Is $\theta$ a variable?

$\theta$ is not a random variable, so $\theta \in \Theta_0$ is not a probabilistic event

This is not always exactly true. The parameter $\theta$ could be generated by a random process.
This is related to Are “Data are fixed” in Bayesian viewpoint and “Data are random” in frequentist viewpoint talking about the same thing mathematically?
The fiducial distribution, p-values and hypothesis tests don't require a frequentist setting where the parameter is not considered a variable. They are more generally a particular method for inference with inverse probability. It is a method that is independent from a prior distribution, but not necessarily a method that is without prior distribution.
Still, it is indeed not possible to express $p(\hat{\theta} \in RR | \theta \in \Theta_0)$ if there is no assumption about a prior for $\theta$. A use of $p(\hat{\theta} \in RR | \theta \in \Theta_0)$ for something different would indeed be confusing. Do you have an example where this is done?
3 The meaning of the vertical bar $|$
The issue is also a bit semantic. In probability theory the vertical bar $P(X|\theta)$ or subscript $P_{\theta}(X)$ has a very specific meaning as conditional distribution. It can however also mean 'given that'.

"The parameter  could be generated by a random process." > Does this occur in a Frequentist setting? I thought the defining characteristic here (which is restated in the link you shared) is that population parameters are non-random.

"Do you have an example where this is done?" > authors condition on the equivalent predicate $H_0 is True$ all the time, e.g. Cohen 1994, Perezgonzalez 2015. Notably, Casella 2002 and Wackerly 2007 are careful not to do this, but they don't really explain the subtlety; Wackerly (pg 493) for example writes "α = P(test statistic is in RR when H0 is true)" which at first glance looks like a conditional probability even though it is not.

@AbhishekDivekar the fiducial distribution, p-values and hypothesis tests don't require a frequentist setting where the parameter is not considered a variable.

@AbhishekDivekar the condition 'when H0 is true' can relate to a point hypothesis. Do they use the expression for a composite hypothesis as well?

My question was specifically about the Frequentist setting, though :)

"Do they use the expression for a composite hypothesis as well?" > the setup of a  composite null is avoided in most texts, including these. This is why I was requesting an earlier commenter (JohnMadden) to provide more details on the general form of the statistical models; this information is frankly not written down anywhere (that I managed to find).

@AbhishekDivekar I wonder whether there are a lot people that consider a purely frequentist setting. I guess that in most settings people use a likelihood $P(X|\theta)$ where the bar means 'given that', and in practice it differs little from 'conditional on'. If you really want to stick to a frequentist philosophy then you can just not call it 'conditional on', but I guess that mathematically it doesn't change a lot (because in practice both Bayesian and frequentist techniques use the likelihood which is 'given that').

I do agree that it might however be better to use $P(X;\theta)$ for a likelihood, even in the Bayesian setting. I never considered this issue before and I see now that it can be confusing.
